Understanding the Definition of Conditional Optimal Transport Path
In this tutorial about flow matching, the authors define a probability path interpolating between $p_0 = N(0, I)$ and a target distribution $q$ as follows (Equation 2.2 of the paper):
$$p_t(x) = \int{p_{t|1}(x|x_1)q(x_1)dx_1}$$, where $p_{t|1}(x|x_1) = N\left(x|tx_1, (1 - t)^2I\right)$.
My question is at time $t = 1$, how does $p_t$ equal the target distribution $q$? Here, $p_{t|1}(x) = x_1$, and the resulting integrand will be $\int x_1q(x_1)dx_1 = E_{X \sim q}[X]$.

I'm not clear on what you're asking about. Where does it say that $p_t$ is equal to $q$ when $t=1$?

In the first paragraph on page 5, the authors talk about designing a probability path $p_t$ that interpolates between $p$ and $q$. So I'm assuming this means that $p_0 = p$ and $p_1 = q$, correct?

$p_{t|1}(x)$ is a probability distribution function (PDF), it's area under the curve has to be $1$, therefore it cannot be equal to $x_1$. That would not be a PDF.
When $t=1$, you'll have $p_{t|1}(x)=\delta(x-x_1)$, which means $x$ is almost surely $x_1$. We use $\delta$ function to describe such cases in continuous domain. $p$ was actually a normal distribution but when $t\rightarrow 1$, it mean approaches $x_1$ and the variance approaches $0$. So, you can imagine a very narrow and long bell shaped curve on top of $x=x_1$.
Dirac delta function, i.e. $\delta$ has nice properties. The following integral evaluates easily:
$$p_1(x)=\int \delta(x-x_1)q(x_1)dx_1=q(x)$$
See the translation property.
